# Using libreOffice calc to fit a plane through a set of 3D points minimizing the total distance

Tags: regression, curve-fitting, libreoffice-calc

Consider a set of 3D points:

```
| y/z |   -1   |    0   |    1   |
|:---:|:------:|:------:|:------:|
|  5  | 19.898 | 19.905 | 19.913 |
|  0  | 19.898 | 19.92  | 19.935 |
| -3  | 19.883 | 19.883 | 19.92  |
| -4  | 19.86  | 19.898 | 19.898 |
```

where the rows are `yi`s, columns are `zi`s and the content are `xi`s.

I want to fit a plane of

```
Ax + By + Cz + D = 0
```

into these points in a way the total distance of:

```
E = ∑ (|Axi + Byi + Czi + D| / √(A^2 + B^2 + C^2))
```

> [image]

to be minimized. Consider that I want to have the absolute deviation `|...|` not the variance as used in conventional regression methods. Also please consider that the dimension of the actual data frame is much bigger, so it will be great if the solution is computationally efficient too.

I would appreciate if you could help me with this issue. Thanks in advance.

**Reference:** equations from [here](https://mathinsight.org/distance_point_plane).

Comment: Can you make external calls to R, Python, Matlab, etc. from within Calc as part of a solution?

Comment: well, are you asking if I can do it? then yes. I do use Python no problem. If you are asking if LibreOffice Calc can do it, then I think it does. I haven't done it myself though. would be happy to learn.

Comment: BTW please help me with a FOSS solution. I don't have a MATLAB license. Python preferably. But Scilab / ScicosLab, Octave, Julia, R... in this order of preference. I haven''t honestly done R much.

Answer (score 1):

This stand-alone Python program should do what you want for the fitting. I do not know how to call it from Calc, or pass data and results back and forth between Calc and Python.

Ax + By + Cz + D = 0

rearranges to

Ax + By + D = -Cz

which rearranges to

(Ax + By + D) / -C = z

That is a 3D surface equation of the form "z = f(x,y)", easily fit with scipy's curve_fit as shown here:

```py
import numpy, scipy, scipy.optimize
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import  Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm # to colormap 3D surfaces from blue to red
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graphWidth = 800 # units are pixels
graphHeight = 600 # units are pixels

# 3D contour plot lines
numberOfContourLines = 16


def SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)

    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 20)
    yModel = numpy.linspace(min(y_data), max(y_data), 20)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(xModel, yModel)

    Z = func(numpy.array([X, Y]), *fittedParameters)

    axes.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=1, antialiased=True)

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data) # show data along with plotted surface

    axes.set_title('Surface Plot (click-drag with mouse)') # add a title for surface plot
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label
    axes.set_zlabel('Z Data') # Z axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def ContourPlot(func, data, fittedParameters):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 20)
    yModel = numpy.linspace(min(y_data), max(y_data), 20)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(xModel, yModel)

    Z = func(numpy.array([X, Y]), *fittedParameters)

    axes.plot(x_data, y_data, 'o')

    axes.set_title('Contour Plot') # add a title for contour plot
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    CS = matplotlib.pyplot.contour(X, Y, Z, numberOfContourLines, colors='k')
    matplotlib.pyplot.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10) # labels for contours

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def ScatterPlot(data):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)
    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data)

    axes.set_title('Scatter Plot (click-drag with mouse)')
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data')
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data')
    axes.set_zlabel('Z Data')

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else thaere can be memory and process problems


def func(data, A, B, C, D):
    x = data[0]
    y = data[1]
    return (A*x + B*y + D) / -C


if __name__ == "__main__":
    xData = numpy.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0])
    yData = numpy.array([11.0, 12.1, 13.0, 14.1, 15.0, 16.1, 17.0, 18.1, 90.0])
    zData = numpy.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.0, 9.9])

    data = [xData, yData, zData]

    initialParameters = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0] # these are the same as scipy default values in this example

    # here a non-linear surface fit is made with scipy's curve_fit()
    fittedParameters, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func, [xData, yData], zData, p0 = initialParameters)

    ScatterPlot(data)
    SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters)
    ContourPlot(func, data, fittedParameters)

    print('fitted prameters', fittedParameters)

    modelPredictions = func(data, *fittedParameters) 

    absError = modelPredictions - zData

    SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
    MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
    RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
    Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(zData))
    print('RMSE:', RMSE)
    print('R-squared:', Rsquared)
```

Comment: that was freaking fast. :) you are awesome. I will go through this and will come back.

Comment: Python is awesome, not me. I am an ant standing on the shoulders of giants, though this gives me a tall appearance.

Comment: sure it is. sure it does. but anyway you are very kind for giving back to the community. :)